# Unexpected end of file on custom Woocommerce template

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

I'm coding a custom Woocommerce theme. All works well in local, but when I deploy on my server, this error occurs when I go to a product details:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /wp-content/themes/customtheme/content-single-product.php on line 231
```

Here's the concerned file code (Pastebin since it's a big amount of code and it display the lines number) : **https://pastebin.com/bzgLQTmD**

I really don't know where is this error given that I don't have it in local development.

I tried code validators, but they didn't gave me any clues.

Comment: First remove this line `<!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->`  and check

Comment: try once removing 'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'columns' => 3,
                'orderby' => 'rand', in this remove only  comma after rand

Comment: Post your code here, the file is not that big.

Comment: @AnkurBhadania Thank you for the tips, I also removed it ;)

Comment: @mega6382 Stackoverflow prevents me from adding all the code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with short tags, which are not enabled by default. So, either enable them from `php.ini` or
Change all of these:

```
<? endif; ?>
```

To Proper full tags like:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the issue!